# update policy for a data class in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I try to use an object from a data class that will update a Composable and declare it as follows:

```
data class CounterState(var counter: Int = 0)
.....
val counterState: CounterState by remember { mutableStateOf(CounterState(), structuralEqualityPolicy()) }
```

`structuralEqualityPolicy()` is the update policy of the Composable and is defined :

> A policy to treat values of a MutableState as equivalent if they are
> structurally (==) equal.

if the property counter changes like with: `counterState.counter++`  the Composable should be updated, but this does not work.

I use Compose version `1.0.0-alpha06`

Any Idea how to resolve the issue?

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Text
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

data class CounterState(var counter: Int = 0)

@Composable
fun dataClassRemember() {
    val counterState: CounterState by remember { mutableStateOf(CounterState(), structuralEqualityPolicy()) }
    Column() {
        Button(onClick = {
            counterState.counter++
        }) {
            Text(text = "Increment")
        }
        Text(text = "Counter value is ${counterState.counter}")
    }
}

@Preview("dataClassRemember")
@Composable
fun dataClassRememberPreview() {
    dataClassRemember()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this instead:

```
data class CounterState(var counter: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(0)})
```

Hope it works,
Anna

Answer (score 0):

Since the composable is observing on the `MutableState<CounterState>`

```
val counterState: CounterState by remember { mutableStateOf(CounterState(), structuralEqualityPolicy()) }
```

When we do `counterState.counter++`, the `state` variable never changes i.e the address of the object is the same.

Suppose if we do something like this

```
counterState.value = CounterState()
```

This would trigger a state change.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a new composition, your mutableState value should be updated. In your case, you only update the content of your value and compose can't know when it is updated. You can simply try this :

```
Button(onClick = {
    counterState = counterState.copy(counter = counterState.counter + 1)
}) { ...
```